# Micronaut custom factory to create JMS configuration is not working

Tags: micronaut

This is a slight modification of the example given on this page: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-jms-aws-sqs-gradle-java.html

In the application.yml we have disabled the micronaut.jms.sqs.enabled=false because we want to manually create the SqsClient and the ConnectionFactory. In order to do so, we provided a local factory that creates two beans. The implementation is given below:

```
@Factory
public class LocalFactory {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalFactory.class);
    @Bean
    @Singleton
    @Named("someSqsClient")
    @Primary
    SqsClient imageRekognitionSqsClient() {
        LOG.info("creating a local image-rekognition sqs client:: sqsConfig -> $sqsConfig");
        return SqsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of("us-east-1"))
                .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create("foo", "bar"))
                .endpointOverride(URI.create("https://localhost:4566"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Singleton
    @Named("myfactory")
    @Primary
    ConnectionFactory imageRekognitionSqsConnectionFactory(@Named("someSqsClient") SqsClient sqsClient) {
        LOG.info("creating a local image-rekognition sqs connection factory");
        return new SQSConnectionFactory(
                new ProviderConfiguration().withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(
                        3
                ), sqsClient);
    }
}
```

The jms-listener is defined as follows:

```
@JMSListener("myfactory")  // <1>
public class DemoConsumer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoConsumer.class);

    private final AtomicInteger messageCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Queue(value = "demo_queue")  // <2>
    public void receive(@MessageBody String body) {  // <3>
        LOG.info("Message has been consumed. Message body: {}", body);
        messageCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    int getMessageCount() {
        return messageCount.intValue();
    }
}
```

However, upon starting the application, the micronaut server fails to start with the following error message:

10:21:06.687 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: No bean of type [io.micronaut.jms.pool.JMSConnectionPool] exists for the given qualifier: @Named('myfactory'). Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.jms.pool.JMSConnectionPool] exists for the given qualifier: @Named('myfactory'). Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).

The issue is in the fact the the local factory never gets invoked and the two beans never get created. Why is that?